# AsyncPostBackTrigger control in ajax

Tags: asp.net-ajax

```
        <div id="divAnswerHeader">
          <div  id="divAnswerSubHeader">
            <h2><asp:Label ID="lblTotalAnsw" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> Answers</h2>
            <div id="divTabs">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="oldestAnswer" runat="server" title="Answers in the order they were given" OnClick="oldest_click">oldest</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="newestAnswer" runat="server" title="Most recent answers first" OnClick="newest_click">newest</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="votesAnswer" runat="server" title="Answers with the most votes first" OnClick ="votes_click">votes</asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPnlLMList" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate> 

      // code.........

     </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers> 
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="oldestAnswer" EventName="Click" /> 
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="newestAnswer" EventName="Click" />
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="votesAnswer" EventName="Click" />
     </Triggers> 
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

in code behind file i have written...........
        protected void oldest_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
    }
    protected void newest_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void votes_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

when i click on newest , oldest , votes  then page_load event fire while i have allready define asynchronous postback so i want to prevent fire page_load event how i will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `Page_Load` event will always fire, you can try wrapping your code inside following

> if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["x-microsoftajax"] == null)
>   {
>            // your code here
>   }

Answer (score 3):

For a partial postback, the page life cycle is still fully intact.  Page_Load still firing is by-design.

http://encosia.com/2007/10/24/are-you-making-these-3-common-aspnet-ajax-mistakes/

What you can do is in your Page_Load event handler, check if you are in the middle of a partial postback.

```
if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).IsInAsyncPostBack)
```